# RTE Editor with autosave functionality in TYPO3 Backend

Tags: typo3, wysiwyg, backend, autosave, rte

Do you know if there is an autosave support in TYPO3's backend RTE Editor ?

So that as you write or edit content inside the RTE editor, the changes you make are automatically saved every 2 minutes.

Found this issue http://forge.typo3.org/issues/18657. Don't want to believe that TYPO3 doesn't support backend(!) RTE Editor autosave.

Comment: It doesn't. But **aloha** frontend editing extension does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TYPO3 has no built in functionality for autosave content!! Strange but true. But as said by  Artur Cichosz, Aloha does that.